# Raspberry Pi Pico not reading a button correctly

Tags: microcontroller, button, python, raspberry-pi-pico

I connected a button to my Pico and would like to see if it is pressed in real-time.

One end of the button is connected to `GPIO 15`, other one to `3v3(OUT)`.

code:

```python
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

button = Pin(15, Pin.IN)

while True:
    print(button.value())
    sleep(.3)
```

It works and responds to my button presses. **HOWEVER**, sometimes Pico says that the button is pressed while it is not. After a few seconds, output goes back to what it should be. How can I remove this delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have an external pull-down resistor on the input pin, enable the internal pull-down.